# i want to load the componant inside the detailed view

Tags: html, angular

i made a template using bootstrap with side bar and top navigation bar but when i click the button in the nav bar it load the component below the page , and as iam a bigneer in angular i didnot figure out what the problem is

thanks for your help

[image]

[image]

how i can show the component in the white area instead of below the navigation bar

my html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{ 'active': navbarOpen }">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>PE</h3>
            <strong>PE</strong>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li class="active">

                <a routerLink="FieldsChart" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
                    Dash Board
                </a>

                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                    Home
                </a>

                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
                    About
                </a>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                    Pages
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
                    Portfolio
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                    FAQ
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
            <li>
                <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
            </li>
        </ul> -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" (click)="ToggleBN()">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    <!-- <span>Toggle Sidebar</span> -->
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <!-- Page Content -->


</div>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

my router

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ChComponent } from './ch/ch.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';



const routes: Routes = [
  {
// main path
    path: '',
    component:HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full' , 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'FieldsChart', component: ChComponent },
    ]
  },
  {
    // main path
        path: 'FieldsChart',
        component:ChComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
//   {
// // not found
//     path: '**',
//     component:NotFoundComponent

//   }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

your help is higly appreciated

edit : after i moved router oulet to the content it solve the problem to load the compnant inside the content but the home page became like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

move `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside`<div id="content">`
as per current code every routed component is outside bootstrap's `<div class="wrapper">`

Comment: it solved part of the problem , but the home screen duplicated inside each other i donot know why

Comment: Oh! So is the HTML you gave actually homecomponent?